# Replicating Changes from Advantage Database Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, database, wpf, postgresql, advantage-database-server

I am looking to create a WPF application that can perform the following:

- Monitor tables in Advantage Database Server (ADS) or PostgreSQL
- Replicate changes from ADS to Postgres, or Postgres to Postgres
- Allow user to select which specific tables to monitor and replicate

I know ADS has replication built in, and that has been an option in the past. However, ADS is going the way of the Dodo in terms of support (thanks, SAP). So for our development, ADS is going to be strictly on legacy support. For new development, Postgres will be our DB of choice. The issue, however, is that we will have to deal with a long period of supporting a combination of both systems for our customers.

That said, if all their systems are ADS, then we're fine. However, if they have ADS and Postgres, or even *just* Postgres, we need a way to replicate data between them. So, back to my original query. I am working to design and develop a WPF application that allows a user to connect to a source DB (ADS or Postgres) and choose which tables they want to replicate data from. Then they pick the Postgres instance for a destination DB. I'm just not sure where to begin.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: This is some development effort, but if there is a Python API for this database, you could write yourself a Multicorn foreign data wrapper to access it directly from PostgreSQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Do you ave any additional info on Multicorn foreign data wrappers? I can Google it for sure, but I'd be wading into unknown territory entirely.

Comment: The web page is [here](https://multicorn.org/). It is not simple, but much easier than writing a FDW in C. Read the PostgreSQL documentation on FDW and familiarize yourself with postgres_fdw, then you understand what it is.

Comment: ADS has an ODBC driver, maybe you can just use odbc_fdw together with the ADS ODBC driver. https://pgxn.org/dist/odbc_fdw/